# How to make requestBodies required in swagger

Tags: c++, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

How do I define a required requestBody in swagger (openapi 3.0) ?

The following generates the request object but the validation methods are trivial and not requiring that the request's properties to be set:

```
/data/{idParam}:
    put:
      tags:
        - Data
      parameters:
        - $ref: "./commonDTO.yaml#/components/parameters/dataIdParam"
      summary: My rquest
      description: |-
        Allows operator to import data.

      operationId: importData
      requestBody:
        $ref: "#/components/requestBodies/ImportDataDTO"


requestBodies:
  ImportDataDTO:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            dataId:
              $ref: "./commonDTO.yaml#/components/schemas/dataID"
            requestHeader:
              $ref: "./commonDTO.yaml#/components/schemas/RequestHeaderDTO"
            dataDTO:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/MyDataObj"
```

What I get out is this:

```
bool ImportData_request::validate(std::stringstream& msg, const std::string& pathPrefix) const
{
    bool success = true;
    const std::string _pathPrefix = pathPrefix.empty() ? "ImportData_request" : pathPrefix;

                    
    return success;
}
```

Instead I should check that the id, name, dataDTO, etc are all set.

I'm using the cpp-pistache-server generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`required: true` on the request body level requires the presence of *any* request body. For example, an empty object `{}` will be valid.

To require specific properties within the body, you need to specify the list of required fields within the `schema`. For example, to require the `name`, `dataId`, and `dataDTO` properties, add the following lines to the schema:

```yaml
requestBodies:
  ImportDataDTO:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          required:        # <--------
            - name         # <--------
            - dataId       # <--------
            - dataDTO      # <--------
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            dataId:
              $ref: "./commonDTO.yaml#/components/schemas/dataID"
            requestHeader:
              $ref: "./commonDTO.yaml#/components/schemas/RequestHeaderDTO"
            dataDTO:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/MyDataObj"
```

Comment: Yeah, so I thought. I made the properties required, and those in turn have other object with required properties. After a couple of levels it gets down to primitives which are also required. But when I gun the generator, the validate function is still unchanged. I don't understand it. Maybe it's a bug in the generator ...

Comment: Seems to be a codegen bug indeed. There's a [similar bug report](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5880) about required query parameters.